# Remove child from a movie clip with several frames?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, flashdevelop

I have a movie clip named MC that has two layers. The second layer has 5 frames and the first layer has only one movie clip named `item` from frame 1 to frame 5.

Then, in my code, I create a new `MovieClip` named `soulItem`, and add the `item` into the `soulItem`, then add `soulItem` into `MC`. Then, the `item` was removed from his parent (`MC`).

Then, something wrong happened when the `MC` goto frame 2. There is a new `item` instance which its parent is `MC`, and is not equal to the `item` in `soulItem`. There are both displayed on screen, and the `numChildren` added 1.

the code are as follows:

```
public function FiveElementBall(MC:MovieClip) {
    var soulItem:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    var item:MovieClip = MC.getChildByName('item') as MovieClip;
    MC.addChild(soulItem);
}

private function update():void {
   MC.gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

And I solved this as follows:

```
private function update():void {
    if(MC.getChildByName('item') != null) {
      dispose(soulItem);
      var soulItem:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
      var item:MovieClip = MC.getChildByName('item') as MovieClip;
      soulItem.addChild(item);//Then, item was removed from MC's Children.
      MC.addChild(soulItem);
    }
    MC.gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

I dispose and initialize `soulItem` again when the new item instance occurs (when frame changed).Then it is right.

But I want to know is my guess right and why it is?

And I can solve this remove `item` from `MC` when it is a child of `MC`, Because the `soulItem` is right, the only fault is that `a new instance of item` appears.(In one frame, its parent is null, nor `soulItem` or `MC`, In other frame, its parent is `MC`).

Comment: Are there multiple keyframes that contain `item` in your `MC`? Or is it only 1 keyframe across all 5 frames?

Comment: Also, the code you posted does not move `item` in any way. You create `soulItem` and add it to `MC` but you don't do anything with `item`.

Comment: The code is wrong, I add the item to soulItem. And item is only 1 keyframe across all 5 frames.

Comment: And I can solve this remove item from MC when it is a child of MC, Because the soulItem is right, the only fault is that a new instance of item appears

Comment: The behavior you describe doesn't sound right. If you only have 1 keyframe across 5 frames, then going to frame 2 will *not* create a new instance. If you return to frame 1 a new instance may be created. I'll elaborate in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want to know is my guess right and why it is?

What's important is where your keyframes are. When the playhead moves to a keyframe that places an instance it will create a new instance if it isn't there already.

For example, suppose your keyframes in `MC` look like this:

[image: timeline]

In this case `item` has one keyframe on frame 1 and it spans 5 frames. This would not result in the behavior you describe: you could re-parent `item` and goto frame 2 and a new `item` instance will *not* be created.

However, if you then go back to frame 1 (ex `gotoAndStop(1)` or `prevFrame()`), the player hits the keyframe that *places* the `item` instance and *will* create a new instance like you describe, if the instance is not found there.

Think of a keyframe as a description of what the player expects to exist at that frame. You can change things *between* keyframes, but when the player reaches a keyframe it will re-evaluate that the display has everything exactly how that keyframe describes, and if not, make it so. There's no way to change a keyframe through code. The best you can do is to avoid moving the playhead to a keyframe that places an instance you intend to modify; for example don't ever go back to frame 1.

For this reason it's not usually a good idea to move timeline instances with code the way you are doing if you have more than one frame. It's better to do it all by code or all by keyframes.

For example, instead of having an `item` instance in the timeline, just export the symbol (for example as `Item`) and create it by code:

```
public function FiveElementBall(MC:MovieClip) {
    var soulItem:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    var item:Item = new Item();
    soulItem.addChild(item);
    MC.addChild(soulItem);
}
```

Comment: I have tested it. It is almost right. And when from frame i `gotoAndStop(i-1)`,  it also create a new item instance. Is it that because the changes of displayed frame is i,..., 5, 1,..., i-1 ? And may you provide me some info about  MovieClip's TimeLine ? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yes, `gotoAndStop(i-1)` where `i=2` would mean you are going to frame 1, which is where the keyframe that *places* the `item` instance is, so a new one will be created if the old one was moved. This is why I'm saying you can avoid going to that keyframe to avoid this problem. What "info about MovieClip's timeline" do you want?

Comment: When i = 3, 4 ,5 and the keyframe is 1, `gotoAndStop(i-1)` would also create a new instance of `item` in my Test. And I want to know something about  how to store and use the data of timeline.

Comment: Ah, yes you are right. This is because going backward considers the "last" keyframe on the current span in order to figure out what should be there. The only way to avoid this is to put a blank keyframe on frame 2 and never go back to frame 1.

Comment: Thank you for your help.